# How @WebAppConfiguration works without servlet or application container?

Tags: spring-test

I am using spring 4 and testng. How @WebAppConfiguration loads the WebApplicationContext and servlets without error when I did not install servlet containers like tomcat at all. Is it possible to access the servlets by url in this situation or must install the web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install a real servlet container. You can think that the servlet container created by the `@WebAppConfiguration` is just a fake and in-memory based servlet container but not a real container like Tomcat. It can only work by programatically invoking its method and cannot invoked by an URL.

The actual implementation of this fake Servlet container consist of  `MockServletContext` , `MockHttpServletRequest` , `MockHttpServletResponse` , `MockHttpSession` and `MockServletConfig` etc...

The idea is that to test a `HttpServlet` , we first configure the HTTP request by the setting the related status of  `MockHttpServletRequest` , then programatically invoke `HttpServlet` under test , and verify the result from the `MockHttpServletResponse`:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FooServletTest {

   @Autowired MockHttpServletRequest request;
   @Autowired MockHttpServletResponse response;

   @Test
   public void test1(){
       request.setParameter("user", "enigma");
       //blablab.


       FooServlet sut = new FooServlet();
       sut.doGet(request, response);

       //Then assert the response is correct by checking its status

   }
}
```

See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-web) for more details.